# TreeMap foreach doesn't change value object

Tags: java, android, treemap

So I have a `TreeMap<Integer, Transmitter>` and through a foreach I am trying to modify an inner attribute of the transmitter, but it feels like it is making a copy of the object in the TreeMap, since it does not change the value in the TreeMap.

My foreach code:

```
        for (TreeMap<Integer, Transmitter> current : transmitterDiagnosticMap.values()) {
            for (Transmitter t : current.values()) {
                String transmitterError = t.printErrorReport(date, appContext);
                if (transmitterError != null)
                    stringsErrorsAndWarnings.add(transmitterError);
            }
        }
```

My printErrorReport code:

```
     public String printErrorReport(String data, Context context) {
        String output = null;
        if (this.writeOnReport()) { // This is the function that will modify the object
            output = data + " - " + this.getTension();
        }
        return output;
    }
    // This is the method that tells whether or not the report will be written, and changes the variable lastStatus if necessary
    private boolean writeOnReport() {
        if (this.status > 0) {
            if (this.lastStatus == 0 || this.lastStatus != this.status) {
                this.lastStatus = this.status;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            this.lastStatus = 0;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What I could notice is that the `Transmitter t` actually changes the value from `lastStatus = 0` to `lastStatus = 1`, but nothing is changed in the TreeMap.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "nothing is changed in the TreeMap"? Obviously the keys and the order of the TreeMap won't change if you just change the value.

Comment: @Dabiuteef I mean the object within the TreeMap (the value). All the value objects in the TreeMap stay with `lastStatus = 0`, even if I change them all to 1 using the foreach provided in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the iterator to mutate the values in the TreeMap. Using `current.values()` will create a copy instead of mutating the object.

You need to iterate over the keys of the TreeMap and update the values.

```
for (TreeMap<Integer, Transmitter> current : transmitterDiagnosticMap.values()) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Transmitter> entry : current.entrySet()) {
        Transmitter t = entry.getValue();
        String transmitterError = t.printErrorReport(date, appContext);
        if (transmitterError != null)
            stringsErrorsAndWarnings.add(transmitterError);
        entry.setValue(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,Anoop. That worked like a charm.